# Error in SSIS package while import from MS SQL to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis

I am working on creating a SSIS package to import data from MSSQL to MYSQL.  I am getting the following error while executing.

```
[ADO NET Destination [16]] Error: The external column "<columnname>" (145) has been out of synchronization with the database column. The latest column has new length: 382 . Use advanced editor to refresh  available destination columns if needed.
```

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: "component "ADO NET Destination" (16)" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA".

```
columnname == "lastname"
datatype of "lastname"
MSSQL - nvarchar(255)
MYSQL - varchar(255)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there might have been a database change on one of the tables.  You might need to refresh the metadata on the source/destination.

Comment: I updated the post with complete error message i am getting after executing the SSIS package

Comment: Could you try deleting the source/destination and recreating?  It is usually a last resort.

Comment: deleting doesn't help

Comment: TTeeple,
Finally package was running successfully.  But, I still didn't know the reason for the error.  I recreated the whole package from the scratch it worked.

Comment: Glad to hear!  Sometimes that is all that is needed :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use advance editor and refresh the meta as well as connection manager.Please do this and let me know if still facing the issue.